# Issue with JQuery DOM and .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#favorite").click(function(){
                     alert('click!')
           });
       });

 </script>
</head>
<body>

   <h4>Favourites <small><%= photo.fav %></small></h4>  
   <button id="favorite" class="btn btn-inverse">Favorite</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, I don't get the alert window, so I think is a problem with the DOM tree, How can I resolve this...?

Thank's advance!

Comment: Please read the jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: if you have not imported the JQuery Function - You would be getting JS error when you use "$"-Symbol ."ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]"
Try this Firefox - Firebug plugin - look into console
$(function() {

Comment: The library is added, but stills no working

Answer (score 4):

Or... You're not including jquery...

**EDIT:** Sarcasm aside, include the JQuery library before your code to be able to use it.

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Here's an example of how it should looks... It works fine.

**http://jsbin.com/osijok/1/edit**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#favorite").click(function(){
                     alert('click!')
           });
       });

 </script>
</head>
<body>

   <h4>Favourites <small><%= photo.fav %></small></h4>  
   <button id="favorite" class="btn btn-inverse">Favorite</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It couldn't go before the closing body tag...the OP's jQuery code is in the `<head>`...which means you want them to load the library _after_ they try to use it? It needs to be included _before_ they use it.

Comment: @MrMangado - The code is fine. Check the example I've put up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple.
You don't have the JQuery library loaded on your page prior to executing methods from that library it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the jQuery JS Library to be able to use functions such as

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ .. etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I resolve this...?

Use plain JavaScript

```
(function(){
  document.getElementById("favorite").onclick = function() { alert('clicked'); }
}());
```

Comment: Why do you have an immediately invoked function expression here?

Comment: Because I wanted it to be inside a function and it makes it private.

Comment: What is private? You are not declaring any variable. In this case the expression does not add any benefit. But it does not matter either. I just want to know why you have it, thanks!

Comment: @FelixKling I honestly did it for style purposes. I know it wasn't necessary. I just like the way it looks